# Magento 2: Custom sort order for product collection(skus, ids etc)

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection

For example, I want collection list in order "**sku2,sku3,sku1**", it is not simple DESC or ASC order. How to achieve it?

Example codes is below:

```
$skus = 'sku2,sku3,sku1';
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'sku', array('in' => $skus)
    );
```

Magento 1.x has a way here [How to specify custom sort order for product collection?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10031/how-to-specify-custom-sort-order-for-product-collection/10034#10034), but it doesn't work on Magento 2:

```
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(e.sku, $skus)"));
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class '.../Zend_Db_Expr' not found in ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do in magento 2 as below way, use `\Zend_Db_Expr`

```
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(e.entity_id, ' . implode(',', $skus).')'));
```

Comment: Up vote. Zend_Db_Expr is working now. But when sku has a dash in it, it will result a error like `Unknown column 'MB04' in 'order clause'`, the example sku is "24-MB04", how to fix it?

Comment: @ArthurSereno I dont know whats the issue for using dash. you can raise new question for same.

Comment: Thanks your advice, raise a new question here now https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191568/product-collection-sort-order-by-skus-fix-the-error-when-sku-has-a-dash-in-it

Comment: ok., some one may know give answer for you.

Comment: Not work for me. I have SKU with spacing. **@Rakesh**

Comment: I also tried using entity_id. but not work. Have you any solution? **@Rakesh**

Comment: i try this but not work

Comment: But the product coming in the last. I wanted to show only that 3-4 products on topo f the listing page

Answer (score 4):

### Number Type (like ids etc.)

```
$ids = '4,5,3,1,2';
$collection = ...; // get the collection
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(entity_id,$ids)"));
```

> `entity_id` is the name of column which you want to sort, you need change it when in different collection, like `page_id`, `block_id`, `banner_id` etc.

### String Type (like skus etc.)

```
$ids = 'sku4,sku5,sku3,sku1,sku2';
$collection = ...; // get the collection
$skus = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $skus) . "'"; //need process string
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(sku,$skus)"));
```

> **Number type** use the solution of "**String Type**" is working too, but I think It is not appropriate.

Comment: Sorting using id. Is this work for you?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh It works for me. Notice product use the **entity_id**, you could see my first code sample.

Comment: I tried but not work for me. When category page load then I set custom price to product and I required to sort that custom price(asc/desc). **@Key**

Comment: @DhadukMitesh You should make sure your collection have the 'custom price' data in it. And order price you could just use codes like  `$collection->setOrder('price', 'DESC')`

Comment: This is not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->_collection->getSelect()->order("FIND_IN_SET(e.sku,'" . implode(',',$skus) . "') DESC");
```

or better

```
$this->_collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("find_in_set(e.sku,'" . implode(',',$skus) . "') DESC"));
```

for me it works but main condition is DESC because in other way this items will be missing