# Product collection sort order by custom skus string, when the sku has a hyphen in it, it will result a error

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection, sku

Product collection sort order by skus could use `$collection->getSelect()->order(new /Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(e.sku, $skus)"));` ([Magento 2: Order product collection by the order string(skus, ids etc) given, not DESC or ASC](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191518/magento-2-order-product-collection-by-the-order-stringskus-ids-etc-given-no)), but when sku has a hyphen in it, it will result a error like below.

### Example:

```
$skus = "24-MB04,24-MB01";
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            'sku', array('in' => $skus)
        );
$collection->getSelect()->order(new /Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(e.sku, $skus)"));
```

### Result:

```
Error filtering template: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MB04' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `e`.*, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (`e`.`sku` IN('24-MB04', '24-MB01')) ORDER BY FIELD(sku, 24-MB04,24-MB01)
```

---

Obviously, the hyphen(-) in the sku(24-MB04) result the **Unknown column 'MB04' in 'order clause'** error, because when the sku doesn't have hyphen(-) in it, the codes work well, so how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a research, finally find the solution, we need **process the $skus string** to fix the syntax error in database query.

```
$skus = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $skus) . "'";
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(sku,$skus)"));
```

Reference: [Add quotes to values in a string separated by a comma php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017046/add-quotes-to-values-in-a-string-separated-by-a-comma-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('eq' => $sku));
```

Also if you want to select SKU's that are looks like your:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => '%'.$sku.'%'));
```

Comment: ASC or DESC order is not my need, what I need is  sort order by custom skus string, you could see the example I given,

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, try this with your collection. I've edited above answer.

Comment: You still mistake my question, the problem is not the `->addAttributeToFilter`, the problem is at the `$collection->getSelect()->order(new /Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(e.sku, $skus)"));`, you could see the more detailed codes I given :)

Comment: Oh sorry... I just can't get what do you want as a result.

Comment: As I see you're trying to filter by column named as your SKU's, but there are, for sure, no columns named like that: "ORDER BY FIELD(sku, 24-MB04,24-MB01)"

Comment: Sorry, give the wrong comment, I'm re-examine this issue. ORDER BY FIELD is a function, but it has some error in it which need to be fixed.